# Computing 'histogram' similarity when the elements can be positively or negatively weighted

Tags: histogram, distance-functions

The 'histograms' I want to compare may have positive or negative bin-values. I use the quotes because I am not sure histogram is the correct name.

The elements that are being sample have associated positive or negative weights, and the bin-value is the sum of the weights of the elements mapped to it. These are 2D 'histograms'.

I can't say too much at the moment about the particular meaning or reasoning behind these 'histograms', they are used by scientists to analyse results of a simulation.

I am hoping to find some literature about such 'histograms' and distance functions that can be used on them.

Comment: Did you mean to share your chart? I don't get your q. What is the issue with negative bins?

Comment: @IcannotFixThis: I believe that many similarity metrics are not formulated to handle negative bin values.